# Create hash table from a 2 elements of a file in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine every 2 elements of a txt file, and hash it to create a hash table, using Python. My code is as below:

```
import hashlib
def SHA1_hash(string):
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha1(string.encode())
    return(hash_obj.hexdigest())
with open("/Users/admin/Downloads/Project_files/dictionary.txt") as f:
    text_file = open("/Users/admin/Downloads/Project_files/text_combined.txt", "w",encoding = 'utf-8')
    for i in f.readlines():
        for j in f.readlines():
            text_c = i.strip() + j.strip()
            n = text_file.write(SHA1_hash(text_c) + "\n")
    text_file.close()
```

The file is 64KB (more than 5700 lines). I tried to run the code but it is not working nor showing any errors. The destination file (text_combined.txt) did not have anything either. Can I ask if I am doing it right or wrong?

I am new to Python as well as programming so please excuse me if I ask any bad questions. Thank you so much.

Comment: The first `f.readlines()` reads the entire file. The second `f.readlines()` has nothing to read. So the inner loop never runs.

Comment: Thank you so much, what should I do in this case? Can you please let me know?

Comment: The solution is to do `lines = f.readlines()`, then do `for i in lines:` and `for j in lines`.  What's the point of this exercise?  You might as well create 32,000,000 random hex strings.

Comment: @TimRoberts It is an exercise in which I need to create a hash table and find the password from it. This is only one of the hash tables. Also, I tried your solution, and it worked, but it might took a lot of time so I'm still waiting

Comment: Then you made a mistake.  I just ran your code with my change, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `f.readlines()` has nothing to read, because you've already read the entire file.

Read the file into a list variable, then iterate through the list.

```
with open("/Users/admin/Downloads/Project_files/dictionary.txt") as f, open("/Users/admin/Downloads/Project_files/text_combined.txt", "w",encoding = 'utf-8') as textfile:
    lines = f.readlines():
    for i in lines:
        for j in lines:
            text_c = i.strip() + j.strip()
            n = text_file.write(SHA1_hash(text_c) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar, also, can I use the same method with 3 words combined?

Comment: Sure, why would that be any different? You should probably use `itertools.product()` for more.

Comment: No, because that would generate 185 billion lines, which would be a 5 terabyte file.  Even doing it for two is going to generate a gigabyte.  You don't do password cracking by generating complete lists like this.

Comment: I understand, then can you please let me know how to solve the type of password like that? Or just show me some keywords so that I can do deeper research about it. The last password that I have to solve was made from 3 words in the dictionary combined, and I don't think I can do it with the dictionary-generating method, thank you.

Comment: Why do you have to save them in a file?

Comment: A brute force password search like this is totally infeasible. If you could test 1 password every microsecond it would take 2 years to try them all.

Comment: I understood, currently, that is the only method that I know (and it's probably the method that the professor wanted me to do, because he warned us that we need to run it for a day or so). I also tried other methods but it doesn't work that well, my coding skill is not good either.

Comment: All I can think is that the professor is showing you how hopeless this method of password cracking is, or how secure passwords made up of at least 3 words are. He can't really expect you to succeed.